# Recursive binary search in Python

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search

I am trying to understand this function with little to no avail. I completely understand what a binary search is but am only new to the concept of recursion but do have a slight grasp on it. I don't really understand what the default values of low and high would be when first calling the function. As of right now I am just including the search space I know the number is in, but what if I don't or I am not sure of the list length? Otherwise, I understand the recursion process going on here as well as the need for low and high being arguments. The function below is provided in the notes by an online course I am taking; however, it wasn't explained in the lecture and contains no docstrings or references about it.

```
def bSearch(L, e, low, high):
    if high - low < 2:
        return L[low] == e or L[high] == e
    mid = low + int((high-low)/2)
    if L[mid] == e:
        return True
    if L[mid] > e:
        return bSearch(L, e, low, mid-1)
    else:
        return bSearch(L, e, mid+1, high)

L = [1,3,6,15,34,84,78,256]
print bSearch(L, 15, 4, 8)
print bSearch(L, 84, 0, 6)
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High and low appear to be indices for which part of the list to search.

In the first example, `15` has an index of `3`, so specifying a lower index of `4` means the `15` isn't included in the search space. In the second example, `84` has an index of `5`, so it is included in the search space spanning indices `0` and `6`.

These indices are also inclusive. If the second example were:

```
print bSearch(L, 84, 0, 5)
```

the answer would be:

```
True
```

If you want to search the entire list, you can simply do:

```
print bSearch(L, 84, 0, len(L) - 1)
```

where the `- 1` is necessary because the search function is inclusive.

Comment: Thank you, I figured this out by running tests but my more direct questions is what if I didn't know where in the list the value was or even the size of the list? Is that just a limit to this function or am I missing a key concept?

Comment: You don't have to know where in the list the value is if you search the entire space. The size of the list is easily available in `len(L)`. I've edited my answer to include this type of search.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! That is what I was looking for. I knew it was possible but I guess I was just drawing a blank. Also, it would probably be way more useful to return the index rather than just a true or false in most cases, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Binary search .

bsearch(list , element to be found , start index , end index).
start index can be taken as 0 at the start of the function
and last index can be taken as len(list)-1

As in question for bsearch(L,15 , 4 , 8 ).
U are searching only between 5th and 9th element where the number is not present.

In the second function call u are searching between first element and 5 th element where a number present.

U can call this function as bsearch(L , 15 ,0 , len(L) - 1) for any other number.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`low` and `high` specify the indices of `L` where the algorithm must search. In the first example, 15 has the index 3. This is not in the interval [4,8] so it will return `false`. In the second example the index of 84 in `L` is 5, this is in the interval [0,6] so this will return `True`.

If the number you are searching for is not in `L` this method will return `False`. Why? Because you end up in the base case of `if (high-low) < 2`. In this case there will be checked against `L[high] or L[low]` being equal to the number you are searching for. If both are not the case, it returns `False`. This is the definition of the logical `or`.

`False or False = False
False or True = True
True or False = True
True or True = True`

If you are not sure about the list length, this will produce an error if the `high` or `low` value you provide are not in the range of `L`. You can add an extra condition so this can not happen, but I think that is out of the scope of that lesson. :)